# How to convert dp into % of the screen (weight)?

Tags: java, android

I have multiple layouts. By all I have hight=0 and and weigth=something. But now I want to add a layout that will allways be 60px. All works perfectly but now I need to know how much weight is 60px because I neet it for something else I am working on. So is it possible to get screen dimensions in dp. NOTE: I need to know the dp for each section. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9UNU.jpg)

How exact can this be?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the screen width and height like this:

`DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE); 
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;`

then you just divide the height you get by the number of layouts you want to display

EDIT: another option would be(if you know the number of layouts at compile time) to give each layout the same `layout_weight` value f.e. `layout_weight=1`

Comment: Yes but which height do I get now? See image?

Comment: you'll get the total screen height, could you share the xml code of this activity for clarification?